# Prove $\phi(t)=\frac 1t$ is Borel function.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

To be specific, $\phi(t)={1\over t} $ (if $t \neq 0$)  or $0$ (if $t=0$).

Please check the process I prove is correct:

I used the definition of Borel measurable or Borel function which is

$\phi^{-1}([-\infty,t])\in B:$ Borel set

Since $\phi^{-1}([-\infty,t])=(0,\frac 1t]\in B$, $\phi$ is Borel function.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You are right in $\phi$ being a Borel function, but you made come mistakes computing the inverse images:

For $t < 0$, we have 
\begin{align*}
  x \in \phi^{-1}([-\infty, t]) &\iff \phi(x) \le t \\
                                &\iff \frac 1x \le t\\
                                &\iff x \ge \frac 1t \land x < 0
\end{align*} 
Hence $\phi^{-1}([-\infty, t]) = [\frac 1t, 0)$, which is a Borel set. 
For $t = 0$, we have
$$ \phi^{-1}([-\infty, 0]) = \phi^{-1}([-\infty,0)) \cup\{0\} = (-\infty, 0] $$
and for $t > 0$, we have 
$$ \phi^{-1}([-\infty, t]) = \phi^{-1}([-\infty,0]) \cup \phi^{-1}((0,t]) = (-\infty, 0] \cup  \left[\frac 1t, \infty\right) $$

Comment: It really helped. You are awesome!! Thanks.