# Is $f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x}, x\neq 0\\ \infty, x=0 \end{cases}$ Borel-measurable? (Using Borel sets)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions, borel-sets, borel-measures

Consider a function $f:\mathbb R\to\overline{\mathbb  R}$ defined as $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x}, x\neq 0\\ \infty, x=0 \end{cases}$$

Is $f$ Borel-measurable?

I followed the answer given here [Prove $\phi(t)=1/t$ is Borel function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217274/prove-phit-1-t-is-borel-function) by [martini](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/15379/martini)

Let $a\in\mathbb R.$

For $a<0,$ \begin{align*}
  x \in f^{-1}([-\infty, a]) &\iff f(x) \le a \\
                                &\iff \frac 1x \le a\\
                                &\iff x \ge \frac 1a \&\ x < 0
\end{align*} 
Hence $f^{-1}([-\infty, a]) = [\frac 1a, 0)$, which is a Borel set.

For $a=0,$

\begin{align*} f^{-1}([-\infty,a])\\ &\iff f^{-1}([-\infty,a)\cup\{a\}\\ &\iff \frac 1x<a\cup\{a\}\\ \end{align*}

from here how to find the interval for $x$? like in the case $a<0$, $x$ was between certain values but in this case $\frac 1x<a\implies \frac 1a<x$ which can't be since $a=0$?

In the answer mentioned was $(-\infty, 0]$

Something similar happens in the case $a>0$.

Comment: Also related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3229778/is-the-function-borel-measurable (that one is proof-verification)

Comment: @amWhy Thanks for your just recent unfair downvotes:)

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f$ does not take on the values $0,-\infty.$ Note also that on $(-\infty,0)$, $f(x)=1/x$ is a bijection; same for $(0,\infty).$ Below we look at all cases of $a\in[-\infty,\infty].$

$a=-\infty:$ $f^{-1}([-\infty,a])=f^{-1}(\{-\infty\})=\emptyset,$ so we're fine.

$-\infty<a<0:$ Here $f^{-1}([-\infty,a])=f^{-1}((-\infty,a]),$ which is the interval $[1/a,0).$

$a=0:$ $f^{-1}([-\infty,0])=f^{-1}((-\infty,0)).$ As mentioned above, this is the interval $(-\infty,0).$

$0<a<\infty:$ In this case

$$f^{-1}([-\infty,a]) = f^{-1}((-\infty,0)\cup (0,a])$$ $$ = f^{-1}((-\infty,0))\cup f^{-1}((0,a])) = (-\infty,0)\cup [1/a,\infty).$$

$a=\infty.$ Here the inverse image is all of $\mathbb R.$

Comment: +1 thank you zhw.

Answer (score 1):

For $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

You correctly proved that, for $a<0$, 
$$f^{-1}([-\infty, a]) = [\tfrac 1a, 0)$$

which is Borel.

For $a=0$, since: 
$ x \in f^{-1}([-\infty, 0])  \iff x<0$.
(Details: Since $0$ is not in the image of $f$, we have: $ x \in f^{-1}([-\infty, 0]) \iff  x \in f^{-1}([-\infty, 0))\iff \frac{1}{x}<0 \iff x<0$).
So 
$$f^{-1}([-\infty, 0]) = (-\infty, 0)$$
which is Borel.

For $a>0$, we have that, for $x<0$, it is true that  $\frac{1}{x}\le a$. On the other hand, we know that for $x>0$, $\frac{1}{x}\le a$ if and only if $x\ge \frac{1}{a}$. So we have:
$$ f^{-1}([-\infty, a])= (-\infty, 0) \cup  [\tfrac 1a, +\infty)$$
which is Borel.

Now, we need to inspect two other cases: $a=-\infty$ and $a = \infty$.

It is easy to see that

$$ f^{-1}([-\infty, -\infty])= \emptyset$$
which is Borel. And

$$ f^{-1}([-\infty, \infty])= \mathbb{R}$$
which is Borel.

So $f$ is Borel measurable.

**Remark 1:** Since the function $f$ is from $\mathbb R$ to $\overline{\mathbb  R}$, to prove it is Borel measurable we need to prove that:

1. For any Borel set $B \subseteq \overline{\mathbb  R}$, $f^{-1}(B)$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb R$.

It can be proved that this condition is equivalent to

2. For any $a \in \overline{\mathbb  R}$, $f^{-1}([-\infty, a])$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb R$.

(Atention:  $a \in \overline{\mathbb  R}$, not just $a \in \mathbb  R$)

Of course, we could also work with $a \in \mathbb  R$ and explicitly check $f^{-1}(\{-\infty\} )$ and $f^{-1}(\{\infty\} )$ to ensure they are Borel set. Any way, to prove that $f$ is Borel measurable, we need to consider the extremes points of $\overline{\mathbb  R}$.

**Remark 2:**
Since $[-\infty, -\infty] = \{-\infty\}$, and since there is no $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)= -\infty$, we have: 
$$ f^{-1}([-\infty, -\infty])= \emptyset$$

Since $[-\infty, \infty]= \overline{\mathbb  R}$ and, for all  $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) \in \overline{\mathbb  R}$, we have that

$$ \mathbb{R} \subseteq f^{-1}([-\infty, \infty])$$

But, since $\mathbb{R}$ is the domain of $f$, we also have

$$f^{-1}([-\infty, \infty]) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$$

So we conclude: 
$$f^{-1}([-\infty, \infty]) = \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Should not be $f(x)=\frac 1x<0$ here $x \in f^{-1}([-\infty, 0])  \iff x<0$ ?

Comment: @Isa  Since $0$ is not in the image of $f$, we have: $ x \in f^{-1}([-\infty, 0]) \iff  x \in f^{-1}([-\infty, 0))\iff f(x)=\frac{1}{x}<0 \iff x<0$.

Comment: Why $\frac 1x<0\iff x<0$ ? I can see it in the graph of $\frac 1x$ that indeed it's true but not formally

Comment: why did you consider $f^{-1}([-\infty, -\infty])$? and what does that notation mean? Also why this $f^{-1}([-\infty, \infty])=\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Isa $1$ is positive so $1$ divide by $x$ will be negative if and only if $x$ is negative. (It is a consequence of the rule of signs for the division).

Comment: @Isa Regarding your second question, I added Remark1 and 2 in my answer to answer it. Please, let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: @Isa I hope I have answered all your questions. Please, let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: Thank you Ramiro that's kind of you. Yes I have a question. why did you proved for $f^{-1}[-\infty,\infty]$? you said that was  necessary for $\infty$ so $f^{-1}[\infty]$ ?

Comment: @Isa The case $f^{-1}(\{ \infty\})$ (or $f^{-1}([-\infty, \infty])$) is trivial. I have included it just for a matter of covering all the details.

Comment: looks weird because seems like you are considering both $\infty$ and $-\infty$ at the same time here $f^{-1}([-\infty,\infty])$ however the case $f^{-1}(\{-\infty\})$ was considered independently

Comment: @Isa When considering $f^{-1}([-\infty, \infty])$, I am considering the WHOLE interval $[-\infty, \infty]$. 

Because, we have already prove that, for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$,  $f^{-1}([-\infty, a])$ is Borel, we know that  $f^{-1}([-\infty, \infty))$ is Borel.  So considering $f^{-1}([-\infty, \infty])$ become actually equivalent to consider considering $f^{-1}(\{\infty\})$.

Comment: Ah. My confusion arises because in one case you just wrote $f^{-1}([-\infty,-\infty])$ and would be natural to write for the other case $f^{-1}([\infty,\infty])$ instead of $f^{-1}([-\infty,\infty])$ now I see that indeed they are equivalent.

Comment: @Isa All our intervals are of the form $[-\infty,a]$ , where $a\in \overline{ \mathbb{R}}$. 
So I considered $f^{-1}([-\infty, -\infty])$ and $f^{-1}([-\infty, \infty])$, just for uniformity.

Comment: aah, now everything makes sense.. lol

Comment: @Isa Great. If you don't have any further question, may I kindly ask you to accept my answer?

Comment: hehehe:) well being honest I liked more the other proof gaved (I could finally understand it completely :D, though I probably won't accept it neither (since he didn't help me to understand my doubts) but as you were very kind and tried to help me, I'll put a +50 bounty on my question and award yours.

Comment: @Isa Thanks very much. I appreciate it.  It is true that there are shorter proofs, but  when I answer I always try to value the good stuff the OP has demonstrated. You had started a perfectly valid proof, but you got stuck. My answer was actually how to complete your initial proof.

Comment: oh I see. Was not mine actually, as you can notice I wrote at the beginning _I followed the answer given here..._ and I choose it because I didn't have any alternatives. Regarding to the bounty I wanted to award it now, but it tells me I need to wait 23 hours.

Comment: @Isa By the way, one of the nice aspects of initial proof you chose (and of my answer) is that it does not require any Topology result. It only uses Measure Theory.

Comment: Ohh, well the word 'nice' is definitely relative. that's the _why_  I liked more the other answer, it was not that easy to follows at first I have to say but then was fine.

Comment: @Isa Yes, the word 'nice' is relative. Actually, different things may be nice in different ways.

Comment: @Isa Do you still plan to accept my answer?

Comment: No, I'll award it with bounty :)

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to prove that if $U$ is open in $\overline {\Bbb R}$ then $f^{-1}U$ is Borel in $\Bbb R.$

Let $g$ be the restriction of $f$ to the domain $D=\Bbb R$ \ $\{0\}.$ Now $D$ is open in $\Bbb R$ and $g:D\to \Bbb R$ is continuous.

If $U$ is open in $\overline {\Bbb R}$ then $U\cap \Bbb R$ is open in $\Bbb R$ and  $$f^{-1}U=A\cup B$$ where $$A=f^{-1}(U\cap \Bbb R)=g^{-1}(U\cap \Bbb R)$$ and $$B= f^{-1}(U \setminus \Bbb R).$$ Now $A$ is open in $D$ by continuity of $g,$ and $D$ is  open in $\Bbb R,$ so $A$ is open in $\Bbb R.$ So $A$ is Borel in $\Bbb R.$

And $B=\emptyset$ or $B=\{0\}$ so $B$ is Borel in $\Bbb R.$

So $f^{-1}U=A\cup B$ is Borel in $\Bbb R.$